# Generating Code from a Source File Using Doxygen

Tags: c++, documentation, doxygen

I'm using doxygen to generate HTML documentation. I have a C++ source file that contains only global functions. All of the global functions are document, and the documentation is properly generated. For all of the headers in the project there is a link to “see the code that this documentation was generated by.” (as a link to the HTMLized code). The CPP file that the documentation has generated does not create a similar link. How can I force it to link to the code, and generate an HTMLized version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `INLINE_SOURCES = YES` in the config file, see [here](http://www.doxygen.nl/manualn/config.html#cfg_inline_sources) for more details.

Comment: Can you do that for just one file?

Comment: @monksy: It might if you play with the `FILE_PATTERNS` tag, setting it to something like `FILE_PATTERNS=<your cpp>.cpp *.h *.hpp`. Not 100% sure about the syntax or side effects...

Comment: Can you just enable that option for only one file. I have many files that are being document but I only need that side effect for one file.